# Wait for both promise and event listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, promise

This is probably a simple problem, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I need to run code when the page is loaded **and** a promise is resolved. Since the promise is a bit long, I want to start the promise first. Here is my code:

```js
// Wait for the promise
myLongFunction().then(() => {
            
    // Wait for the page to be load and rendered
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

        // I do awesome stuff here
    });
});
```

Sometimes, when `myLongFunction()` is too long, the DOM is already loaded and the event has already been triggered. I never do my *awesome stuff*.

The following always works:

```js
// Wait for the page to be load and rendered
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

    // Wait for the promise
    myLongFunction().then(() => {

        // I do awesome stuff here
    });  
});
```

I prefer the first option since `myLongFunction()` is running while the DOM is loaded. Is there a way to wait for both event properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Have a promise resolve when the load event fires.
- Use `Promise.all` to wait for them both.

e.g.

```js
const loadPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    addEventListener('load', resolve);
});

const otherPromise = myLongFunction();

Promise.all([loadPromise, otherPromise]).then((results => {
    // Both promises have now resolved
});
```

Comment: @Fifi is this works for you, please accept the answer

Comment: My function returns a variable. I was wondering how to get it with PromiseAll, but I thing this is OK

Comment: @Fifi your *variable* response of your *long fn* (`otherPromise`) will be passed in `results[1]`.